# UITableViewCell.contentView reports wrong width

Tags: uitableview, autolayout

How is this possible?

```
(lldb) po contentView
<UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7fd0f3470c90; frame = (0 0; 400 699.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fd0f346c980>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd0f3461930>>

(lldb) po UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=320, height=568)
```

Screen has 320px width but an empty custom table cell has 400.

Comment: Are you using autolayout? Can you post the code that generates this, or the storyboard/xib?

Comment: Yes, I'm using autolayout. There's nothing special with the code. I am adding a custom table cell to a table, that's all. Also it seems this width is same on iPhone 6 Plus simulator. It's always 400px.

Comment: Ok, I've found what's wrong. Although I used a table view controller, the table view was getting a wrong width. Always 400 px. I added constraints to pin it to the superview edges, and the problem's gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase someone bumps into this, the culprit was the tableview. When I pinned it's edges to the superview, the cells started to work correctly.